# Retrieving postback values of dynamically created RadioButtonList does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, repeater, radiobuttonlist

The situation is as following:
I am creating a survey where there are X questions and each question could be answered with six choices. Since there is only one choice allowed, I use a RadioButtonList and since there are X questions, I use a ASP.NET Repeater to generate the RadioButtionList.

ASPX code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ActualSurvey">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="headLeftCol leftCol headerCol">
                    Bank
                </th>
                <th class="headerCol">
                    1
                </th>
                <th class="headerCol">
                   2
                </th>
                <th class="headerCol">
                    3
                </th>
                <th class="headerCol">
                   4
                </th>
                <th class="headerCol">
                    5
                </th>
                <th class="headerCol">
                    6
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="leftCol">
                <%# ((ReliabilityMeter.DataAccessLayer.Bank)Container.DataItem).DisplayName %>
            </td>
            <td class="midCol" colspan="6">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" CssClass="radioButtonList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="2"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="3"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="4"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="5"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="6" Selected="True" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="leftCol">
                <%# ((ReliabilityMeter.DataAccessLayer.Bank)Container.DataItem).DisplayName %>
            </td>
            <td class="midCol" colspan="6">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl2" runat="server" CssClass="radioButtonList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="1"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="2"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="3"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="4"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="5"/>
                    <asp:ListItem data-rating="6" Selected="True" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<tr class="footerRow">
    <td colspan="7">
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Insturen" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I postback, I got the following code:
C# Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ActualSurvey.DataSource = new BankManager().GetBanks();
            ActualSurvey.DataBind();
        }
    }

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the page is valid and the request is valid
        if (Page.IsValid && IsValidRequest)
        {
            //Iterate through each repeater item to find the RadioButtonList
            foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in ActualSurvey.Items)
            {
                var bank = repeaterItem.DataItem as Bank;
                RadioButtonList radioButtons = repeaterItem.Controls.FindControl<RadioButtonList>();
                var rating = FindRating(radioButtons);
            }
        }
    }
```

At SubmitButton_Click the ActualSurvey.Items is filled but empty inside, I guess that it has got something to do with the Page Lifecylebut I can't figure it out... Also Page.Request.Forms does not contain the values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ListItem definitions seems to me weird.

```
<asp:ListItem data-rating="1"/>
<asp:ListItem data-rating="2"/>
```

Did you try to change them like below

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1"/>
<asp:ListItem Value="2"/>
```

Comment: I do not want to show a Value but I want to add a HTML-attribute which identifies the rating. data-* is HTML 5 standard for custom-attributes

Comment: Hmm, I am ashamed. It seems that this custom HTML-attribute did mess it... I will have to add the HTML-attribute in another way then.

Comment: You can also use custom attribute like data-rating="1", but i think Value is required to function properly.

Comment: I did not work when i used the custom attribute so for now I will stick with Value. The problem with Value is that is shows besides the radio button and that I do not want...

Comment: This was the answer by the way ^_^ . The ASP control does not like it when HTML 5 attributes are added like this.

Answer (score 0):

DataItem is only valid before items are rendered, e.g in DataBinding event.
After the post back the repeater rebuilds it's content from ViewState.

One way to keep that property valid is to perform data-binding in Repeater.Init event

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ActualSurvey" OnInit="ActualSurvey_Init"> 
 ...
</asp:Repeater>

....
```

cs:

```
void ActualSurvey_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      object banks = Cache["ActualSurvey_Banks"];
      if (banks == null)
      {
         banks = new BankManager().GetBanks();
         Cache.Insert("ActualSurvey_Banks", banks);
      }

      ActualSurvey.DataSource = banks;
      ActualSurvey.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse ActualSurvey is not available in the Ctor of my page. I guess Page_Init would do fine as well? :)

Comment: It does not work. I do not necessarily have to use DateItem. I want to use the values wich are posted by the form.

Comment: Ah, I just wanted to post that the event was never triggered